# JS Performance issues in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, tinymce

I am having trouble with a script in Safari. The basic function of the script is that it uses jQuery UI's Sortable function to enable sortable `div`'s. Within the `div`'s are TinyMCE instances. In order for the TinyMCE content to persist after the DOM change, I have to run a TinyMCE function that clears the content on Sortable start and restores it on Sortable stop.

After implementing this workaround for persisting the content, I am seeing terrible performance issues when trying to place a `div` in Safari 7.0. The performance is fantastic in Chrome and Safari.

After doing some Javascript profiling in Safari, I am seeing the following:

[image: Safari profile]

And here is a drilldown of the `isVisible()` function that is taking 1.82s:

[image: Safari profile drilldown of isVisible]

A few things to notice:

- Some of these functions are being called almost half a million times :o
- None of these functions are originating from code I've written
- They appear to be related to autofill
- None of these expensive functions show up in the Chrome or Firefox profiles

My assumption is that when TinyMCE's functions run to restore the content, it's changing some of the `textarea` fields, which are likely prompting some sort of autofill activity.

So...I have three questions:

1. What are these functions?
2. Is there any documentation for them?
3. Can I suppress them?

Comment: Are DOMElements being removed and re-added, with listeners on them? If so, and the event listeners aren't being cleared, this would be a memory leak and could possibly result in what you are seeing, since when the elements are added back the listeners are being duplicated, so it can grow exponentially and each action with them doubles, triples, quadruples, etc. Depends on if it is doing anything like that which would affect eventListeners.